# MVC and Javascript to test for a null value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using MVC .net core to populate my ViewModel.
I am trying to build a chart and a canvas is not being created if the value is null. This is working fine.

regardless if I add a test in the script section to test for null

```
if (Model.AssessmentDetailByCategChart!= null) 
{
```

or testing for element exists (and it should not )

```
if ($('#canvasRadarTech').length > 0) {
```

I have this crash. Could you please help with the proper syntax?

[image]

[image]

If I add a "@" in front of the model, then the rest of the code is not compiling.
[image]

Comment: If you debug `Model.AssessmentDetailByCategChart.ElementAt(0)` and `Model.AssessmentDetailByCategChart.ElementAt(0).Assess_ChartData`, do you get any value?

Comment: Your error is a C# exception, not a javascript exception so your second code snippet where you are using jquery to see if the canvas exists probably won't be helpful. I think your issue is the value of Model.AssessmentDetailByCategChart is non-null, so it satisfies the expression if your if statement, but the value is not an IEnumerable. What is the value when you debug?

Comment: I have attached the errors when accessing both

Answer (score 0):

Use `@if` for fields in Model

Wrap the rest with a `<text>` tag, to indicate the rest of the code is JavaScript instead of C#

```
@if (Model.AssessmentDetailByCategChart!= null)
{
    <text>
    if ($('#canvasRadarTech').length > 0) {
    {
        //do your things here...
    }
    </text>
}
```

Comment: The code will not compile if I add the @if

Comment: @lbrettsinclair the syntax error is because it recognized your code as C# wrongly, I updated my answer

Comment: I get <text>" and "</text>" tags cannot contain attributes

Comment: @lbrettsinclair I cannot reproduce your problem, can you give more details, e.g. giving your code in text?